# Check subclasses in Python

Tags: python, class, types, telethon

I'm currently working with the telegram cli, now, I'm at one point where I have to check if the user is inside a particular group whit these few lines of code

```
with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.messages.CheckChatInviteRequest(hash=hash))
```

I'm obtaining as a result with `print(type(result))` :

`<class 'telethon.tl.types.ChatInvite'>` this if I'm not inside the group

`<class 'telethon.tl.types.ChatInviteAlready'>` this if I'm already inside.

Now, what I want to do is something like:

```
if type(result) == telethon.tl.types.ChatInvite:
    print('You are not inside the group')
```

but obviusly this doesn't work, it gives me this error `NameError: name 'telethon' is not defined`
how can I check the subclasses?

Thankyou :)

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: sorry, my bad, I've updated the question :)

Comment: Did you *import* `telethon`?

Comment: Use `isinstance(result, ...)`.

Comment: @chepner tried but I'm getting the same error

Comment: @ user2357112 telethon is the library, I'm importing stuff from telethon, but I can't import telethon, my guess is that it reads `telethon. ..` not in a correct way

Comment: It looks like `types` is exposed directly from `telethon`; does `isinstance(result, telethon.types.ChatInvite)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can import `ChatInvite`, do this:

```
from telethon.tl.types import ChatInvite

result = get_result(...)

if isinstance(result, ChatInvite): 
    print('You are not inside the group')
```